# Access @ref name given to a Blazor component within the component

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor-server-side

I am making a Blazor server side pager component that will be dropped on pages to allow lists to have Previous/Next buttons. Each pager component is given an @ref like this:

```
<Pager @ref="UserPager" PageInfo="UserSearch.PagingInfo" PageEvent="PageSwap" />
```

At the moment the parent page deals with storing the UserSearch.PagingInfo object to allow the page to be reloaded with the state of the paging held. I would like to push that logic in to the component, but to do this I would need to be able to know what instance of the component is loading to ensure the correct cached info is bought back.

Can I access the @ref value in the child component itself? If I can't access that value I can pass another parameter to do the same job, but if I can avoid that all the better.

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ref doesn't name a component, it specifies the already existing field that holds the component. You need to add a `Pager UserPager` field to your code

Comment: `Can I access the @ref value in the child component itself?` that's a different question and has to do with components in Blazor, React and other SPAs. Components don't have references to their parent. That would make composition and rendering a *lot* harder. Components bind to their parent's parameters and raise events to them. To avoid repeated bindings, a nested component can use [Cascading Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/cascading-values-and-parameters?view=aspnetcore-7.0) to bind to parameters specified on a parent tag

Comment: Your question is moot - the `@ref` that you get back is the instance of the component class - the component can always reference itself as `this`